# Why is an item in the ViewBag not propagated to the _Layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a SiteNavigation class that is being updated in the Initialize event of my base controller e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class SiteNavigation
{

    public SiteNavigation()
    {
        IsSummarySelected = true;
    }

    public Model.Dtos.Folder[] Folders { get; set; }


    public bool IsSummarySelected { get; set; }

}

protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    var siteNavigation = new SiteNavigation();

    siteNavigation.Folders = GetMeMyFolders() as Folder[];

    ViewBag.SiteNavigation = siteNavigation;

}
```

and in the controller the IsSummarySelected property is changed to this value.

```
ViewBag.SiteNavigation.IsSummarySelected = false;
```

When I access the property in the _Layout file with this line of code, the value is ALWAYS true. It's as if the nav object is being New'd up again and the constructor is setting it to true.

```
 @if (ViewBag.SiteNavigation.IsSummarySelected)
```

I've tried casting the nav object back to a variable and setting the property that way too, no dice. Any help would be appreciated.

Call me baffled!

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy pasted your code into my sample mvc project, and changing IsSummarySelected in my action correctly was reflected in the _Layout file. Are you certain your controller's assignment is getting hit, and you're not reassigning it afterwards somewhere else?

**Edit:** Your issues are an example of why I think it's a bad idea to use ViewBag for anything other than a localized quick fix. Debugging dynamic global objects is no fun. Refactoring suggestion: Make a site Navigation property in your base controller

```
SiteNavigation siteNavigation;
public SiteNavigation SiteNavigation
{
    get
    {
       return siteNavigation;
    }
    set
    {
        siteNavigation = value;
    }
}
```

and replace all references to ViewBag.SiteNavigation with this. Then create a custom WebViewPage and put in it.

```
public SiteNavigation SiteNavigation
{
    get
    {
        return ((BaseController)ViewContext.Controller).SiteNavigation;
    }
}
```

This won't fix your problem, but now you can just stick breakpoints on the get and set properties of SiteNavigation, and it should be very easy to debug your issue now.

Comment: @AFinkelstien The Initialize method works well for what I'm doing, but I got rid of the IsSummarySelected property in lieu of doing it through routing.. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I fill my *TempData["SplitterIsCollapsed"]* when **Filters** are invoked then via *OnResultExecuting* method. Additionally i fetch a property state from my *UserContext* class, which is registered only once per session: *builder.RegisterType().As().CacheInSession();* .
Basic info: I use **DependcyInjection**!

Assignment of the Filter to the Controller:

**Controller:**

```
[LayoutTempData]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //....
}
```

**FilterAttribute class:**

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Infrastructure.Filters
{
    public class LayoutTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IUserContext _userContext;
        public LayoutTempDataAttribute()
        {
            _userContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserContext>();
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.Controller.TempData.ContainsKey("SplitterIsCollapsed"))
                context.Controller.TempData["SplitterIsCollapsed"] = _userContext.LayoutInformation.SplitterIsCollapsed;
            else
                context.Controller.TempData.Add("SplitterIsCollapsed", _userContext.LayoutInformation.SplitterIsCollapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

The Splitter part of the **_Layout.cshtml** looks like:

```
@{Html.Telerik().Splitter().Name("Splitter1")
    .Panes(panes =>
        {
            panes.Add()
                .Size("300px")
                .Collapsible(true)
                .Collapsed((bool)TempData["SplitterIsCollapsed"])
                .Content(<div>asdfasdf</div>);
            panes.Add()
                .Collapsible(false)
                .Scrollable(false)
                .Content(<div>content2</div>);
        })
     .Render();
 }
```